# How to match the first / after specific character

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I've been looking at multiple questions but couldn't find an answers... even though I'm sure that my issue is easy to solve....

I have the following pattern :

`https://www.website.domain/blablabla/my-page-path-here`

I would like to capture `website.domain`. I've been playing with https://regex101.com/, and I've come up with this until now :

`www.(.*)(\/.*?)`

but doesn't work...

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `www\.([^/]+)` and get your match from first captured group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind: `(?<=www\.)[^\/]+`

Explanation:

`(?<=www\.)` - matches next expression if it's preceded by `www.`

`[^\/]+` - matches one or more any characters excluding `/`

Comment: Full match: `website.domain/blablabla`

Answer (score 0):

Close but this might be a bit better

`(?!w{1,}\.)(\w+\.?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\.\w+)` Match: "website.domain"

It selects the domain and sub domain and ignores the `www`

It you want to keep the `www` just drop the first group

`(\w+\.?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\.\w+)` Match: www.website.domain